# Elasticsearch cluster status still yellow even with 0 unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a situation where unassigned shards are 0 but still Elasticsearch cluster status is yellow. On the other side, some of the index data is getting duplicated. We see same data entry being made more than 3 to 4 times. Below is the current status of the cluster

```
{
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 5,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
  "active_primary_shards": 3888,
  "active_shards": 7775,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 1,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 99.98713991769547
}
```

Elasticsearch logs

```
[2019-11-22T02:42:19,929][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [elasticsearch-master-b94556bc6-q62jc] [gc][1605322] overhead, spent [347ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2019-11-22T02:42:20,424][WARN ][o.e.x.m.MonitoringService] [elasticsearch-master-b94556bc6-q62jc] monitoring execution failed
org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportException: Exception when closing export bulk
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$1$1.<init>(ExportBulk.java:95) ~[x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$1.onFailure(ExportBulk.java:93) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound$1.onResponse(ExportBulk.java:206) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound$1.onResponse(ExportBulk.java:200) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.common.IteratingActionListener.onResponse(IteratingActionListener.java:96) [x-pack-core-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.lambda$doFlush$0(ExportBulk.java:164) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onFailure(ActionListener.java:68) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.local.LocalBulk.lambda$doFlush$1(LocalBulk.java:115) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onFailure(ActionListener.java:68) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ContextPreservingActionListener.onFailure(ContextPreservingActionListener.java:50) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$1.onFailure(TransportAction.java:91) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:173) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:81) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:87) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:76) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:407) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:484) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ClientHelper.executeAsyncWithOrigin(ClientHelper.java:74) [x-pack-core-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.local.LocalBulk.doFlush(LocalBulk.java:108) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk.flush(ExportBulk.java:60) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.lambda$doFlush$1(ExportBulk.java:154) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.common.IteratingActionListener.run(IteratingActionListener.java:81) [x-pack-core-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.doFlush(ExportBulk.java:170) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk.flushAndClose(ExportBulk.java:84) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk.close(ExportBulk.java:74) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.Exporters.export(Exporters.java:196) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.MonitoringService$MonitoringExecution$1.doRun(MonitoringService.java:258) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:624) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportException: failed to flush export bulks
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportBulk$Compound.lambda$doFlush$0(ExportBulk.java:156) [x-pack-monitoring-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.xpack.monitoring.exporter.ExportException: failed to flush export bulk [default_local]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are no ingest nodes in this cluster, unable to forward request to an ingest node.
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ingest.IngestActionForwarder.randomIngestNode(IngestActionForwarder.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ingest.IngestActionForwarder.forwardIngestRequest(IngestActionForwarder.java:51) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    ... 23 more
```

What could be the reason for this? How do we resolve this?

Comment: post your elasticsearch logs. your _health response says there is 1 shard in initializing state.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Updated question with elasticsearch logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can let Elasticsearch "explain" why it could not allocate a shard by using the [Cluster allocation explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-allocation-explain.html): `GET /_cluster/allocation/explain`

Comment: Cluster is green now. However, it fluctuates between green and yellow. Also, data is getting duplicated

Comment: It's normal that Elasticsearch occasionally relocates shards for optimal distribution of the load, but eventually relocated shards get cleaned up. If you see the your cluster state changing that might be an indication that you face latency issues (slow network). Check the API when and post the response when your cluster state changes from green to yellow.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. How do we check network issues? I am unable to make any API calls. I tried /_cat/shards and it times out

Comment: This is becoming a too generic topic. You detect network issues if you can no longer communicate with Elasticsearch (as you just did). You can also see entries in logs when Elasticsearch takes action due to a node no longer being reachable.

I recommend investigating into the missing shards topic first. You only need to be able to communicate with one node in your cluster. Work locally on the host of a node and querying ES. You need to ensure that `http.host` does include the value '_local_'. So you can learn how your cluster looks like and why shards cannot be allocated.